# How to return an array based off matching key value pair of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

I have the following two arrays:

```
const raceOptions = [
    {
        "label": "race_option_american_indian_alaska_native",
        "value": "American Indian/Alaska Native"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_asian",
        "value": "Asian"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_black_african_american",
        "value": "Black/African American"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_native_hawaiian_pacific_islander",
        "value": "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_white",
        "value": "White"
    },
    {
        "label": "prefer_not_to_say",
        "value": ""
    }
]

const selectedRace = [
    "American Indian/Alaska Native",
    "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander",
    "Black/African American"
]
```

How can I combine / filter these arrays to output a new array as follows?

```
const filteredArray = [
  'race_option_american_indian_alaska_native',
  'race_option_native_hawaiian_pacific_islander',
  'race_option_black_african_american'
]
```

Comment: `selectedRace.map(race=>raceOptions.find(o=>o.value.includes(race))).map(o=>o.label)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `.forEach()` method of the Array object you can iterate over the elements inside your `raceOptions` array. Inside it's callback function you need to compare the current element's `.value` property with all the elements inside the second array `selectedRace`.

This can be done with the array's `.find()` method which will return element's based on a search query. The filtered elements finally need to be pushed into the new array `filteredArray`.

```js
const raceOptions = [{
        "label": "race_option_american_indian_alaska_native",
        "value": "American Indian/Alaska Native"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_asian",
        "value": "Asian"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_black_african_american",
        "value": "Black/African American"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_native_hawaiian_pacific_islander",
        "value": "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander"
    },
    {
        "label": "race_option_white",
        "value": "White"
    },
    {
        "label": "prefer_not_to_say",
        "value": ""
    }
]

const selectedRace = [
    "American Indian/Alaska Native",
    "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander",
    "Black/African American"
]
let filteredArray = [];
let result;
selectedRace.forEach(element => {
    if (result = raceOptions.find(element2 => element2.value == element)) {
        filteredArray.push(result.label)
    }
});
console.log(filteredArray);
```